# Documentation of mp3transform

Tags: java, audio, mp3

Is there any documentation of **mp3transform**? I'm trying to play **.mp3** files, which AudioInputStream doesn't understand. I'm writing in Java.

I think, that this library is not the best of every possibility. Do you recommend any different libraries for playing .mp3 files?

I'm going to do some "serious" stuff with this music, so I'm gonna need methodes like loop(), getTime(), pause() or something. In this case, more means better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my last project I faced the same problem, so I used JavaFX Media Features with my swing application. JavaFX media supports both audio and video and also contains many playback functions.

You can use JavaFX to create your player and also can embed JavaFX into your Swing project. In this case you do not need to add any libraries integrated into your project. 
Please use this link to know more : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm

Simple implementation would be,

```
       @Override
       public void startPlay(Stage stage) throws Exception {
           Media file = new Media("file:///Audio/song.mp3"); //Path to file
           MediaPlayer myPlayer = new MediaPlayer(file); 
           myPlayer.play();
       }
```